# How two recursion function in inorder walk BST works?

Tags: recursion

Hello guys I have a question about how two recursions actually work in this particular piece of code

```
void inOrder(struct node* r)
{
    if(r!=NULL){
        inOrder(r->left); //  a
        printf("%d ", r->value); // b
        inOrder(r->right); // c
    }
```

}

so In which order the a , c  function will be execute

thank you

Comment: Left, Parent, Right

Comment: Please explain what you did to trace the execution, and where you're confused.  Stack Overflow already has a variety of answers to this level of question; how did those not explain what you need?

Comment: actually I thought that if this is recursion InOrder(a) should call to itself which means that calling to void inOrder(struct node* r ) which If I call it in that way I am testing if it is null so if it is null I am out of the body of if else I am doing again InOrder call which I mean (a) The problem is I did not understand maybe how recursion actually works But I know it should call to itself

Answer (score 2):

You are probably referring to the call tree of recursion, here a little gif that will explain it visually :

[image]

way better that I could with words.

I made the gif but the work is NOT mine, I took the prints from this presentation `www.cc.gatech.edu/~bleahy/cs1311/cs1311lecture12wdl.ppt`

Answer (score 0):

The same as if they weren't recursive calls: (a) goes first, then the `printf`, then (c).

Comment: But should not be first (a) and then check again( if statement ) since is not NULL then call again is it not how recursion suppose to work?

Comment: That's a different call from a different function (which happens to have the same name, even the same code, as this one), and not what you asked.